# Cannot publish Excel Add-On on Microsoft Partner Center

Tags: excel-addins

I am trying to publish a simple Excel Add-on through Microsoft Partner Center under Office Store, but I get a message saying that "This account is not publish eligible." Attached below is the screen print containing this message. Looking forward to some kind soul to help me here :)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be because your verification status is pending. Check it at Developer settings >> account settings.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because your verification status is pending OR your Tax profile/Payout profile is not completed.
Check for these in your Partner center account.

Comment: you need more details